# Can I block others from seeing my Python code?

Tags: python

Can I block others from seeing my code? I'm working on something in Python. As I save it, it's a (.py) and everyone can right-click and see the code. This is unlike C where I generate an .exe that you can't simply (!) read.

Comment: First, why do you want to do this?

Comment: No, not really. See [Undecompilable Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15087339) for a more in-depth discussion.

Comment: I just want to hide it for my own reasons...

Comment: @Ofek.T. I can only think of you trying to scam someone.

Comment: Not at all.
I have a reason that doesn't <include> any scam of any kind.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code

Comment: doesn't converting you code to .pyc help. I always have modle sbeing imported in a small "main" script, importing leads to creation of pyc's, which is what i ship to who-so-ever I wrote the code for (along with a small <projectname>_main.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the assembly code generated by the process of the compilation in C. The code is not hidden : it's a bit more complex to read, because it is ASM. But it is totally and definitively not hidden :)

Python is made by Open Source community, so the idea is not about hiding your code. If ever you want to make a .exe from a Python code, you can have a try to Py2Exe or Freeze :

- http://www.py2exe.org/
- http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze

Cheers,

K.

Comment: To read assembly || binary file is not quite simple

Comment: @Ofek.T. : ASM is sometime simple for people as like as Python is simple for others, especially in RE community :)